# How can extend /home partition size

Tags: fedora, mount, partition, lvm, disk

On my work computer my **/home** folder keep filling. There are enough space in ssd but i don't know how to use it to make my **/home** partition bigger.

```
[dummy@localhost ~]$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7.8G  1.5M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   20G   13G  6.3G  67% /
tmpfs                    7.8G  8.0K  7.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p1           906M  135M  708M  16% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p3           953M   14M  940M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/fedora-home  4.9G  4.1G  603M  88% /home
tmpfs                    1.6G   44K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

```
[dummy@localhost ~]$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda2            8:2    0 931.5G  0 part /run/media/dummy/Data
└─sda3            8:3    0 711.5K  0 part 
nvme0n1         259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0   954M  0 part /boot
├─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0  46.6G  0 part 
│ ├─fedora-root 253:0    0    20G  0 lvm  /
│ ├─fedora-swap 253:1    0   2.1G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─fedora-home 253:2    0     5G  0 lvm  /home
└─nvme0n1p3     259:3    0   954M  0 part /boot/efi
```

Can i take space from **fedora-root** and give it to **fedora-home**?
And there is **200gb free space** but i can not extend **Partition 2** because of **EFI** in the middle:
[SS from gnome disk utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V6v7.png)

How can i add them to **/home**?

EDIT:

```
[dummy@localhost ~]$ sudo lvextend -L +5G /dev/mapper/fedora-home
  Insufficient free space: 1280 extents needed, but only 0 available
```

```
[dummy@localhost ~]$ sudo pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme0n1p2
  VG Name               fedora
  PV Size               <27.09 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              6933
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          6933
  PV UUID               sn9DgH-bUXj-YEHP-zE7J-sJ3o-xhAO-ckq5gk
```

```
[dummy@localhost ~]$ sudo pvs && sudo vgs
  PV             VG     Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/nvme0n1p2 fedora lvm2 a--  27.08g    0 
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  fedora   1   3   0 wz--n- 27.08g    0
```

Comment: Do you want to reduce space from `fedora-root`? Because I see you have `46.6G` in your volume group and it seems you still have about `19.5G` free space. So you can take that space from the volume group and resize the home partition.

Comment: How can i do that? I dont want to crash anything. Adding 10G to /home is enough for me, even 5G is enough.

Comment: @feinaps Can you share the output of `pvs` and `vgs` ?

Comment: I added their output to question

Comment: Ok that explains. So your Physical Volume is 27G and your Volume Group is 27G. So did you run `pvresize /dev/nvme0n1p2`  ?  If so, after that run `partx -u /dev/nvme0n1p2`  and use `lvresize -r -L +[SIZE]G  /dev/mapper/fedora-home`   where `SIZE` is the desired size you want to assign to this Logical Volume

Comment: Hey now its done, thank you both of you. Do you know any guide/tutorial that explain how to manage disks/storage? I wish i understand these commands.

Comment: @feinaps, please do not self answer in your own question, add a separate answer (you can event accept it after a while).

Comment: @Archemar I couldnt accept the comment so i wrote it to my post. But allright.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `46.6G` in your volume group (`nvme0n1p2` partition) and according to your `lsblk` output it seems you still have free space (about `19.5G`). Thus  there's not need to reduce the space from `fedora-root` logical volume.

You can simply use these commands to extend your home partition/volume:

```bash
sudo lvextend -L +5G /dev/mapper/fedora-home
```

And:

```bash
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/fedora-home
```

Or what is better (all in one command):

```bash
sudo lvextend -rL +5G /dev/mapper/fedora-home
# `-r` or `--resizefs` are equivalent.
```

You can change `+5G` to other values such as `+10G`, `+100M` (any value you want, but make you have the enough space in your volume group)

Comment: After the `lvextend` command i got: `Insufficient free space: 1280 extents needed, but only 0 available`

Comment: Maybe the volume is not allocatable (you can know it by using `sudo pvdisplay`). If that's the problem then this should work: `sudo pvchange -x y /dev/mapper/fedora-home` and then apply again `lvextend`

Comment: Note that `resize2fs` is only for filesystems of type `ext2`, `ext3` or `ext4`. If a different filesystem type is used, the filesystem resizing tool will be different. For example, for XFS the command is `xfs_growfs /home`, i.e. it takes as a parameter the mountpoint instead of the device name.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon i added output of `pvdisplay`

Comment: @telcoM thanks for the information! I was not sure about the filesystem supported by `resize2fs`. What about `growfs` (I remember a command called like that, but not sure when it should be used )

Comment: I've also noticed that `lvextend` has the option `-r` to resize the filesystem at once. I think that should be a better solution and works for any or almost all filesystems supported by lvm

Comment: @feinaps seems to be allocatable, then the problem may be related to volume group or the logical volume. Provide what Valentin asked you, it should be useful.

Comment: `lvextend -r` uses `fsadm`, which is a newer common command for resizing filesystems. It currently supports ext2/3/4, XFS and ReiserFS filesystems, but can and hopefully will be expanded in the future. It might not exist in older systems. `growfs` could be an UFS-specific command in *BSD operating systems; I don't recall seeing it on Linux.

Comment: You can also use `sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/fedora-home` to allocate the remaining storage.

Comment: @telcoM thanks, that's very useful information. About UFS I remember reading in askubuntu an answer using `growfs`, but maybe that's very old and that file system is no longer used in Linux.

Comment: @meijin3 sure! And that's better for adding all the free space without having to specify the exact size.